# DBCursor to ResultSet

Tags: java, mongodb, resultset

I have a java application which use the normal jdbc connection to mysql. But I have to change the application backend immediately to mongodb. But I would like to maintain jdbc resultset as such to avoid huge effort. So is there any way to convert DBCursor to ResultSet.

Comment: Do you understand the differences between an RDBMS like MySQL and a NoSQL database like MongoDB?

Comment: Yea. I know. I changed back end. The response format is something similar when we use mongo driver for java. So if any suitable way to my need it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use design patterns on this one.

You should use the "Adapter pattern".

Create an ResultSetAdapter class that implements the ResulSet interface. There you can simulate the ResultSet behavior but internally using a DBCursor. Now you have to override functions like next()... I suggest you to use the BasicDBObject API which has functions like getInt()... that will facilitate your job.